# jQuery check if something changed with interval

Tags: jquery

i want to check all second if someting is changed from API call.

I get the data here

```
   var data= [];
   $.getJSON(url, function(results){
      var history = results.history;
      $.each(history, function(index) {
        data.push(history[index].currenthashrate);
      });
    });
```

The data is there...

Than i build an "if" to check the new and old data

```
newdata = data;
    if(newdata.length == olddata.length) {
      console.log("old old old old old old old old old old old old")
    } else {
      console.log("new new new new new new new new new new new new")
      drawChart(data, onlinedata, timestampdata);
      console.log('new');
      console.log(newdata.length);
      console.log('old');
      console.log(olddata.length);
      olddata = data;
    }
```

so i tried to give newdata before and check the newdata.length with the olddata.length. If matched he spam old old old ...

When not match, spamming new new new and give data that i get before to chart.

But idk why, the olddata has length = 39 and the newdata = 0... but why? i give them the same data one before if, one in if.

I only want to draw the chart again, if something changed...

Thats the complete code

```
setInterval(function() {
  getChartData();
}, 10000);

var olddata = '';
function getChartData() {
   url = 'myapiurl.com....';
   var data= [];
   $.getJSON(url, function(results){
      var history = results.history;
      $.each(history, function(index) {
        data.push(history[index].currenthashrate);
      });
    });

    newdata = data;
    if(newdata.length == olddata.length) {
      console.log("old old old old old old old old old old old old")
    } else {
      console.log("new new new new new new new new new new new new")
      drawChart(data, onlinedata, timestampdata);
      console.log('new');
      console.log(newdata.length);
      console.log('old');
      console.log(olddata.length);
      olddata = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: A much better solution would be to trigger an event when you change the `data`, then hook your logic to that event handler.

Comment: But how? Thats the only way i know to do it but its not working

Comment: To show you that we'd need to see the code where `data` is set and also where it gets updated

Comment: I postet it. Its all there. Top its the data created and pushed with data and under that directly the if

Comment: That doesn't show where `data` is changed, only that you provide it as an argument to the `drawChart()` function

Comment: Its an interval around it and changing write new every interval round... thats all... drawChart is complete different thing, thats only running with the data

Comment: Ok, you need to help us understand what you want to achieve by elaborating a bit more, so that we can help you. Where does the **olddata** var comes from and what does it contain? Where are you getting your AJAX response from? I mean, maybe share some code from the server side. And most of all, what event triggers the AJAX call? Are you using the **setInterval()** function for your requests? Are you sure you absolutely have to return the whole data on each call? Shouldn't you be returning just the new data (if there is anything new to return)?

Comment: I updated my question. Please look and the bottom of question. there is complete Code. olddata is empty and filled after the if is failed and the newdata and olddata not matched. If its the same, olddata 
I dont know a better way to get api data changes